Hot to run a Javascript file stored in AWS in a Flutter webview?
I am not able to run a javascript file stored in AWS location in a Flutter webview. I am using webview_flutter package. Any suggestions to fix this issue?
I tried runJavaScript method from WebViewController class. But the javascript file in AWS is not loaded in my webview in Flutter app..

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Maybe, it's seems to be below cases.
-- Ensure Correct URL:
Double-check the URL you're using to load the JavaScript file. Ensure that it's accessible and correct. You can try opening the URL in a web browser to verify that it loads the JavaScript file as expected.

-- Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS):
AWS S3 buckets are often restricted by default to prevent unauthorized access. Make sure that CORS settings for your S3 bucket allow requests from the domain where your Flutter app is hosted. You might need to configure CORS rules in the AWS S3 bucket settings to allow your Flutter app's domain to access the JavaScript file.

-- Permissions:
Ensure that the JavaScript file in your AWS S3 bucket has the appropriate permissions set to allow public access or access from your Flutter app.

-- Testing on Different Platforms:
Test your Flutter app on both Android and iOS devices/emulators to see if the issue is platform-specific. Sometimes there might be differences in behavior between platforms.

-- Error Handling:
Implement error handling to catch any errors that might occur while loading the JavaScript file. You can use the onWebViewError callback of the WebView widget to handle errors.

WebView(
  initialUrl: 'https://YOUR_AWS_BUCKET/YOUR_JS_FILE.js',
  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  onWebViewError: (error) {
    print('WebView error: $error');
    // Handle the error here
  },
)

-- Debugging:
Use debugging tools like Chrome DevTools to inspect network requests and debug JavaScript code execution within the WebView. You can enable remote debugging in the WebView by setting the debuggingEnabled parameter to true.

WebView(
  initialUrl: 'https://YOUR_AWS_BUCKET/YOUR_JS_FILE.js',
  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  debuggingEnabled: true,
)

